# What is the difference between grouping config via @import and @ContextConfiguration.?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-test

What is the difference between below two ways of loading configuration.

1. Two independent config classes are loaded via @ContextConfiguration in test class.
2. Import one config into another config and load the single into @ContextConfiguration in test class.

I thought both pushes the configuration into the common pool. But i see a difference. I have two global interceptor one is in java.config and another in xml.config. If i follow 2nd approach above, both interceptors are loading.

But if i follow 1st approach, only one interceptor is loading based on whether i'm invoking xml based gateway or java based gateway.

https://github.com/manojp1988/Learning/tree/JavaDSL/Sample1

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy({
 @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext.xml"}),
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfiguration.class),
 })
public class SampleTest {}
```

**Updated:**

```
@Bean
  @GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = "*_EL*", order=3)
  public WireTap wireTap() {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow approach #1, both interceptors are actually being loaded... just in *different* `ApplicationContexts`.

`@ContextHierarchy` instructs the *Spring TestContext Framework* to load a **hierarchy** of contexts.

Thus, the two configuration setups you have are not identical with regard to contexts. When you use `@ContextHierarchy`, the XML components can only see other beans defined in the XML `ApplicationContext` (i.e., the top level of the hierarchy); whereas, the Java DSL components can see all components (i.e., those configured in Java Config **and** those configured in XML, since the XML context is the *parent* of the Java Config context).

I believe this is actually what you want...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfiguration.class)
public class SampleTest { /* ... */ }
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.model")
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ImportResource("/applicationContext.xml")
public class SpringConfiguration { /* ... */ }
```

If you don't want `SpringConfiguration` to import the XML config, you can alternatively use the following to achieve the same behavior:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class SampleTest {

    @Configuration
    @Import(SpringConfiguration.class)
    @ImportResource("/applicationContext.xml")
    static class Config {}

/* ... */

}
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Thank you Sam. But if you say java config in my class knows both config in XML and Java, then why xml interceptor didn't work when i invoke. hello.sayHello("Manoj"). Context loaded from Java config should have both XML configuration and Java configuration correct?

Comment: With the current code in your repository you are **not** creating a context hierarchy, so the XML interceptor _does_ intercept the "Manoj" message: `@Test
 public void test() {
  hello.sayHello("Manoj");
  xmlSer.sayHello("Jeeva");
 }` outputs `XML Intecepted Manoj / 
DSL InterceptedManoj / 
XML Intecepted Jeeva / 
Hello Jeeva / 
DSL InterceptedJeeva`.

Comment: If you follow approach #1 -- as I mentioned before -- you are in fact creating **two** contexts, and the XML interceptor cannot see flows in the child context.

Comment: So, just by defining configuration inside @contextheirarchy, we cannot expect that it will all load in a single context. We need to import one config into another.  What might be the purpose i need multiple context in my application?

Comment: Exactly. The whole point of `@ContextHierarchy` is to load multiple contexts and configure them in a hierarchy of parent-child contexts. See the [Context hierarchies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-ctx-hierarchies) section of the reference manual for details. Typical use cases for hierarchies are also outlined in the reference manual.

Comment: You might also find the [Mixing XML, Groovy scripts, and annotated classes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-mixed-config) section of the reference manual enlightening.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, I would appreciate it if you would _accept_ it. ;)

Comment: One more doubt i have, If you see in my updated question section above,  I am loading the interceptor configuration in new applicationContext. I could access the wiretap as bean in my child context, but I couldn't use the @GlobalInterceptor in my chid context. So child context inherit only beans from parent?

Github files in the same project:
/Sample1/src/main/java/com/config/DSLInterceptor.java
/Sample1/src/main/java/com/config/SpringConfiguration.java
/Sample1/src/test/java/com/sample/SampleTest.java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84315/discussion-between-manoj-and-sam-brannen).